# Netbeans 8.2 won't run the project

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

i'm new at java language. I try to make my first program that refer from Youtube.
but when i click "run" button, it won't work.
I don't know why but all the build or the code is successful. Maybe i have some little some mistake there..(?)
Can anyone help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9AKq.png)

Comment: Goto *superuser*  ... This site is programming only.

Comment: @Jonasw Questions about tools specific to programming (such as an IDE) are on topic for [so].

Comment: I'm not sure we can really help you with only the information you provided. Can you provide us with (1) the exact steps you took to end up at this point, (2) the code you're trying to run, (3) a few screenshots showing the problem?

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me recently.  Right-click the project, Properties, Build->Compiling, Un-check "Compile on Save." This happened after I opened another project when I already had one loaded. Not sure if that was the root cause. Unfortunately, when I toggled Compile on Save back on the project would not run or debug.

Answer (score 0):

in left side panel there was project panel. inside this panel your project exist.select project and left click on it.it open menu. in menu there is run option will there.

but before running project just make sure that your class has been set as main class.

f6 is short cut to run project in netbeans.